# in ggplot 2 the facet_wrap variable name is not appearing on the faceted graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

When I am rendering the following code I am getting the correct graph, however, the label of the faceted variable assembly_no does not appear on the graph.
[image: the graph below]

```r
hp %>% 
  filter(assembly_no > 10) %>%  
  filter(position == 1) %>% 
  count(assembly_no, party) %>% 
  mutate(party = fct_reorder(party,n)) |> 
  mutate(assembly_no = as.factor(assembly_no)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(n, party, fill = party)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~assembly_no,
             labeller = "label_value",

             scales = "free_y" )+

  labs(x = "Total number of seats", 
       y = "Political Party", 
       title = "Total number of seats by political parties")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: We don't have the data set `hp` to test your code.

Comment: `labeller` should be either a (labeller) function or a lookup table. See the online doc.

Comment: Is this just to remove the argument `labeller="label_value"`?

Comment: removed the labeller argument, still the output is the same graph. Let me know how best I can paste a sample of the data here.

Comment: assembly_no party position
         <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1          11 BJP          1
 2          11 INC          1
 3          11 INC          1
 4          11 BJP          1
 5          11 BJP          1
 6          11 INC          1
 7          11 INC          1
 8          11 IND          1
 9          11 BJP          1
10          11 INC          1
# ... with 205 more rows

Comment: added the sample data above, let me know if you need any additional  columns there.

Comment: happy to send the data over email if required:).

Comment: Save the data frame just before calling `ggplot`, let's say to `hp2`. What is the output of `class(hp2$assembly_no`? `levels(hp2$assembly_no)`?

Comment: class(hp2$assembly_no)
[1] "factor"
> levels(hp2$assembly_no)
[1] "11" "12" "13

Comment: What theme do you use? What you show is not the default one. It's possible that the labels are hidden by the theme.

Comment: Do you have a line with `theme_set` anywhere in your code?

Comment: hey yuk, this finally solved my problem.  I removed/commented out all theme_set plus other theme-related updates, and then used theme_dark() n I was able to see the faceted variable name on the graph. you guys are amazing:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247832/discussion-between-onkaronkar4-and-yuk).

Comment: Just posted it as an answer. Comment there if you have other related questions.

Answer (score 1):

What theme do you use? What you show is not the default one. It's possible that the labels are hidden by the theme.

Check if you have a line with `theme_set` anywhere in your code.

Comment: hey yuk, this finally solved my problem. I removed/commented out all theme_set plus other theme-related updates, and then used theme_dark() n I was able to see the faceted variable name on the graph.